# "This app is using PhoneGap 3.3.0. We are ending support for Cordova versions below cli-6.5.0 on 1st December, 2018."

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

Phonegap also allows the user to upload code online and make apk so the user doesn't have to install PhoneGap in the local machine. I have created apk like this before also (about 2-3 years ago). but now when I upload my code to the phonegap website it's showing me this error "This app is using PhoneGap 3.3.0. We are ending support for Cordova versions below cli-6.5.0 on 1st December 2018." I cant understand, if I am using PhoneGap online and not in my local machine, how can the version be a problem!! Please Help me with this

Comment: create new cordova project, replace new `www` folder (i guess). with your `www` folder and try to build. Also install plugins if you are using any.

Comment: Check the config.xml, you might have the old phonegap versión the there

Comment: I dont know what are you talking about. you might not get what I tried to say. I have not installed phonegap in my local muchine. Instead I am just using phonegap website. I upload the zip file of my code and the website makes apk of it. that's it. then why it's showing me that error. please tell me if you know

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
...
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
...
```

check `phonegap-version`

Comment: there is no config.xml file in my code. I am not using phonegap locally on my machine but I am uploading zip file of my code to build the apk